# Comparing collection with another collection using cypher

Tags: neo4j, comparison, cypher

I have a case where i have to compare all elements in a collection with another collection using cypher, to see if the items are equal (ignoring order of elements). I ended up writing cypher like this one below

> **MATCH (users:user) WHERE all ( condition0 IN ["admin","user"] WHERE condition0 IN ['admin','readonly'] ) return user.**

The above query is wrong for sure, but i am trying to see other alternatives through which i can form a query to achieve the result.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `=` operator:

```
return [1,2,3] = [1,2,3]  //true

return [1,2,3] = [1,2]  // false

return [1,2,3] = [3,2,1] // false
```

`=` checks also if the two collection are fully identical. To ignore ordering you need to sort both collections before using a combination of `UNWIND` and `ORDER BY`:

```
with  [1,2,3] as coll1, [3,2,1] as coll2
unwind coll1 as c    // sort coll1
with c order by c, coll2
with collect(c) as coll1s, coll2
unwind coll2 as c    // sort coll2
with coll1s, c order by c
with coll1s, collect(c) as coll2s
return coll1s = coll2s
```

Answer (score 0):

The above partial answer (to ignore ordering) by @Stefan works well after slight modification to avoid 'Variable coll2 not defined' syntax error.

```
with  [1,2,3] as coll1
unwind coll1 as c    
with c order by c 
with collect(c) as coll1s, [3,2,1] as coll2
unwind coll2 as c    
with coll1s, c order by c
with coll1s, collect(c) as coll2s
return coll1s = coll2s
```